# API ignoring my input on POST

Tags: import.io

I am sending this body via API POST to extractor I created with app.

```
{"input":{"website/url":"http://www.targetsite.com/"}}
```

No matter what URL I put in, it always returns me the results from the same page (I think it must be the one I trained it on).  I can put any string in there and it just totally ignores it.

GET works fine but I would much rather use POST.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this should work, here is a worked example

```
curl -b authcookie -XPOST 'https://api.import.io/store/data/f53e3905-c5d0-457a-befd-d13a3a421bcf/_query' -d '
{
    "input": {
        "webpage/url": "http://www.ikea.com/us/en/search/?query=chair"
    }
}
'
```

compared to:-

```
curl -b authcookie -XPOST 'https://api.import.io/store/data/f53e3905-c5d0-457a-befd-d13a3a421bcf/_query' -d '
{
    "input": {
        "webpage/url": "http://www.ikea.com/us/en/search/?query=light"
    }
}
'
```

table versus light results. If you look in the json of the response it should tell you the url that the results are returned from:-

```
 "pageUrl": "http://www.ikea.com/us/en/search/?query=light",
```

You can also try out this yourself on our api docs:-

http://api.docs.import.io/#!/Query_Methods/queryPost

Comment: If I put ikea into my code then it works fine.  If I put my own connector then it always just gives me the same page.  I will email you my connector id.  This happens on your test tool also.

Comment: maybe connector definition doesn't have the input mapped correctly. Let me the guid details and it should be clear.